# python django: create a new virtualenv for each django project?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Do you create a new `virtualenv` every time you start a new project?

I'm going through some tutorials on the web and they create a virtualenv first then `pip install django` in the `virtualenv`. But there's one tutorial that i saw saying that you wouldn't create a project within the virtualenv and its only used for dependencies.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you _want_ to use the same environment for multiple projects? You can use a virtualenv for any project, so long as the environment is activated.

Comment: @zeantsoi sorry. I guess I'm trying to figure out what the convention is when dealing with projects in django. Because I have Django already installed, but theres some tutorials that would still install django within a virtualenv. I'm new to this. I'm familiar with RoR. Is this similar to having like a gemfile, if you're familiar with that?

Comment: Each project presumably has its own versioned dependencies. Using a virtualenv is a way to manage those dependencies on a project by project basis.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I do.

Virtualenvs help you keep the dependencies required for a project organised and manageable. If you have a django 1.7 project, it will require django1.7 and thus install it in your virtualenv. Without a virtualenv, you might decide to take on a project that requires django1.10. This means your django1.7 project might break. To avoid such a scenario use a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely depends upon you either you wants to work in a

```
virtualenv
```

or not .
But it is strongly recommended to use **virtualenv** as its seprate your new project from other installation of the system.

If you are using python index package(pip) then in your virtualenv just type the command:

> pip freeze

[Image showing package installed in virtualenv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guhOR.png)and all the package install in virtual environment will be shown.

And it is separate from the original install of your system you can try it outside virtual environment by typing **pip freeze**[Image showing package installed on my System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awwvP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer creating a virtualenv for each project (whether it is a django project or not)

This allows isolating projects (and their dependencies) from each other.

Check out [pew](https://github.com/berdario/pew#usage), it makes it super easy and cheap to get lots of virtualenvs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the common practice among Django users to create virtualenv for every project. You can make it even faster and easier using [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). It helps you to keep every project environment independent of each other, so you do not have to worry about the conflicts between dependencies.

I personally do create a virtualenv for each project.