# Creating another virtualenv for a new Django project

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I'm learning Django and Python. If it is right that I understood, I need to create a new virtualenv per Django project.

[python django: create a new virtualenv for each django project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676315/python-django-create-a-new-virtualenv-for-each-django-project)

I installed virtualenv when I was following a Django tutorial before. I want to create an application to practice. so I'm trying to install a new virtualenv.

However powershell shows me this.

[virtualenv installation error?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNqmc.jpg)

How can I install another virtualenv in this case? 
could you please give me an advice or link to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to reinstall the `virtualenv` package. Just run `virtualenv <NAME>` to create a new virtual env. Run `virtualenv --help` get information

Comment: I thought I need to reinstall the virtualenv. Now I know what to search. I will search and try it again. Thank you very much Ksullich!

Comment: Slightly off-topic but if you are new to Python and Django I would suggest learning `pipenv` as it is the officially recommended tool: https://packaging.python.org/guides/tool-recommendations/#application-dependency-management

Comment: Read about `virtualenvwrapper`. It can help you to manage your's virtualenv's

Comment: Thank you very much guys ! I will search all of them !

Answer (score 0):

I think you think wrong in here. **Start new virtualenv** meaning start a virtual env for a specific project not reinstall  a new package **virtualenv**

After ***pip install virtualenv*** try  to run this when want to create a new virtual env for a project

`cd my_project_folder_1
virtualenv my_project_1`

for case you want to *start a new virtualenv for new project*

`cd my_project_folder_2
virtualenv my_project_2`

https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: Thank you for this ! My understanding was absolutely wrong. I will try this way. Thanks !